# Warp disk section to rows of equal radius

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to warp a section of a disk (e.g. an octant) in an image to something similar to a triangle, where each row of the triangle consists of the pixels with the same distance to the center of the disk (i.e. the same radius).
[image: Stylized version of the input and output]

So far, I have tried the midpoint circle algorithm for distances from 1 to r_max (radius of the disk) to query pixels with the same radius. This has, however, the drawback of missing pixels.

In another attempt, I have used polar coordinates (r, phi) with the usual transformation from Cartesian coordinates. With a fixed r, phi varies from the minimum angle to the maximum angle by increments of e.g. 1/r and selects the pixels of the arc. The result is slightly better than the previous algorithm, but some rows are longer than rows with a greater radius. I attribute this to rounding precision when converting from float to int.

Hence, my questions would be:

1. Is there sort of a standard algorithm to achieve what I am trying to do without the flaws of my previous attempts?
2. If not, how would one choose the step size for the angle phi in order to reduce rounding problems?

Comment: In your first attempt, rather than iterate over the pixels of the input image and find where they land in the output image, you can try iterating over the pixels of the output image and determining where to grab them from the input image - that way you'll have no gaps. Or, do as you did and use `cv2.inpaint()` to fill the gaps.

Comment: You might consider providing some concentric circles or something to use as a test input and show your expected and actual output along with your code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, the comment about going from the output image to the input image definitely increased the quality already. This is the right direction.